# Gulp File Watch with BrowserSync

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm trying to get my Gulp File working.

Currently it isn't detecting any of my html, sass or JS changes. SASS and JS isn't compiling into the assets folder - this was working until I began to use browserSync... I did have it detecting the html changes but now that isn't working either after I tried to make my gulpfile more efficient.

I need some experienced eyes to see what am I doing wrong below...

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "latest",
    "gulp-util": "latest",
    "gulp-sass": "latest",
    "gulp-uglify": "latest",
    "gulp-concat": "latest",
    "gulp-connect-php": "latest",
    "gulp-rename": "latest",
    "browser-sync": "latest"
    }
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect-php'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

// Change these values
var jsSources = ['assets/scripts/*.js'],
    sassSources = ['assets/sass/*.scss'],
    sassSources = ['**/*.php'],
    outputDir = 'assets',
    virtualHost = 'annual-review-2016.dev';


// Log Errors
gulp.task('log', function() {
  gutil.log('== My Log Task ==')
});

// Manage CSS
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('sassSources')
  .pipe(sass({style: 'expanded'}))
  .pipe(concat('app.css'))
    .on('error', gutil.log)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('outputDir'))
});

// Manage JS
gulp.task('js', function(){
    return gulp.src('jsSources')
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
          .on('error', gutil.log)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('outputDir'));
});


// Live Reload in Browser
gulp.task('connect-sync', function() {
  connect.server({}, function (){
    browserSync({
      proxy: 'annual-review-2016.dev'
    });
  });
});


// Watch the Styles and Scripts on Save
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('sassSources', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('jsSources', ['js']);
  gulp.watch('phpSources').on('change', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
});


gulp.task('default', ['js', 'sass', 'connect-sync', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have duplicate declaration of sassSources
2. You need to remove quotation mark in `gulp.dest('outputDir')`, otherwise gulp will write the output to `/outputDir` instead of `/assets`

And for auto-reloading you need to include `.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));` at the bottom of your pipe chain (under gulp.dest in 'sass' task for example).